# What's the proper way to implement constant variable?

Tags: javascript

I found the following in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals)

```
// THIS WILL CAUSE AN ERROR
function f() {};
const f = 5;

// THIS WILL CAUSE AN ERROR ALSO
function f() {
  const g = 5;
  var g;

  //statements
}
```

But there is no description of proper way to do. So how should I implement?

Answer (score 0):

ECMAScript 5 doesn't really support this. There's a couple tricks you could use though.

You could try something like this

```
var f = (function() {

  var g = 5;

  return function() {
    return g;
  };

})();
```

Now, every time you run `f()`, you will also get `5`, and it's impossible to change the value of `g`

---

Another thing you could do is use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```
var f = {};

Object.defineProperty(f, "g", {
  configurable: false,
  value: 5
});

f.g; // 5
```

Even if you try to change the property, `f.g` will stay set to `5`

```
f.g = 10;
f.g; // 5
```

---

If you're working with CommonJS style modules, you sort of get this functionality for "free". Again, `g` is non-configurable and always guaranteed to be 5.

**a.js**

```
var g = 5;

function foo() {
  return g;
}

module.exports = foo;
```

**b.js**

```
var a = require("./a");

a(); // 5
```

Comment: For the first example, one might do this: `f = function(){ return 6; }`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, I was just trying to demonstrate how functions can depend on normal vars to stay the same if you "protect" them in an anonymous closure. I felt `function() { return 5; }` was a little too contrived.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [`const`'s MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Browser_compatibility),

> **The current implementation of const is a Mozilla-specific extension and is not part of ECMAScript 5.** It is supported in Firefox & Chrome (V8). As of Safari 5.1.7 and Opera 12.00, if you define a variable with const in these browsers, you can still change its value later. It is not supported in Internet Explorer 6-10, but is included in Internet Explorer 11. The const keyword currently declares the constant in the function scope (like variables declared with var).
>
> Firefox, at least since version 13, throws a TypeError if you redeclare a constant. None of the major browsers produce any notices or errors if you assign another value to a constant. The return value of such an operation is that of the new value assigned, but the reassignment is unsuccessful only in Firefox and Chrome (at least since version 20).
>
> const is going to be defined by ECMAScript 6, but with different semantics. Similar to variables declared with the let statement, constants declared with const will be block-scoped.

`const` is not part of ECMA Script 5, so it may not have to supported by all the environments and browsers.

To have the similar behavior, you can see [macek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22755283/1903116).